# Duhamel's principle for solving constant-coefficient linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

From the [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duhamel%27s_principle#Constant-coefficient_linear_ODE)

> Suppose we have a constant coefficient, m$^{\text{th}}$ order inhomogeneous ordinary differential equation.
>
> $$P(\partial_t)u(t) = F(t) ,$$
>
> $$ \partial_t^j u(0) = 0, \; 0 \leq j \leq m-1 $$
>
> where
>
> $$ P(\partial_t) := a_m \partial_t^m + \cdots + a_1 \partial_t + a_0,\; a_m \neq 0. $$
>
> We can reduce this to the solution of a homogeneous ODE using the following method. All steps are done formally, ignoring necessary requirements for the solution to be well defined.
>
> First let $G$ solve
>
> $$P(\partial_t)G = 0, \; \partial^j_t G(0) = 0, \quad 0\leq j \leq m-2, \; \partial_t^{m-1} G(0) = 1/a_m. $$
>
> Define $H = G \chi_{[0,\infty)} $, with $\chi_{[0,\infty)}$ being the characteristic function of the interval $[0,\infty)$. Then we have
>
> $$P(\partial_t) H = \delta .$$
>
> in the sense of distributions.

I don't understand this last line. Where does the $\delta$ function come from? Because $P(\partial_t)G$ is $0$ everywhere, so in particular, shouldn't $P(\partial_t) H=G \chi_{[0,\infty)}$ also be $0$ everywhere? Why are we concentrating all of its mass at $0$?

Comment: To answer your question, take $G(x) = 1$, it satisfies the system $\partial_t G = 0,\quad G(0)=1$. However, if we multiply it by $\chi_{[0,\infty)}$, the differential equation becomes $\partial _t  \chi_{[0,\infty)}(t) = \delta_0$. The discontinuity of $G\chi$ in zero gives you $\delta$.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Isn't it required that $\partial^{m-1}_tG=\frac{1}{a_m}$? With $G(x)=1$, wouldn't we have $\partial^{m-1}_tG=0$?

Comment: In my example $m=1$, with $a_1=1$, hence the initial condition is merely $\partial^0_t G(0) = G(0)= 1$.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Ok, and you're also taking $a_0=0$?

Comment: Yes, in that example $P(\partial_t) = \partial_t$, hence $m=1$, $a_0=0$, $a_1=1$.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy in the general case, what's the use of requiring $\partial_t^{m-1}G(0)=\frac{1}{a_m}$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56584/discussion-between-man-in-green-shirt-and-tzakrevskiy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P(\partial t)$ be our differential operator, and $H$ be a solution in the sense of distributions of $P(\partial t)H(t)=\delta_0$. Consider now a "good" function $f(t)$ define $F = H\ast f$ - the convolution in the sense of distributions.

The differential equation satisfied  by $F$ is easy to guess - by the properties of distributional convolution,
$$P(\partial t) F(t) = P(\partial t) (H\ast f )= (P(\partial t) H)\ast f = \delta\ast f = f,$$
which allows you to solve the initial differential equation with an arbitrary "good" function $f$ on the right hand side (we omit the exact nature of those "good" functions).

Comment: just for clarity, by $\delta_0$ do you mean the same thing as $\delta$? As in a function (strictly speaking, not really a function) that's zero everywhere, has integral $1$, and has all its mass concentrated at the origin?

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt yes, it is a delta-distribution.